# Python Scrapy Without Splash

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a website that uses an AJAX request for showing the content.

I tried to simulate the AJAX call, but it uses a different token in its cookie every time it sends the request, so I get "500" error and can not access the server.

So I went for the second option (i.e. scraping the website using splash) I installed it with docker and I'm running it on port 8050.

In `http://localhost:8050` I have a test `render.html` console. I write the site address and when it supposed to show all the content (including the ones that produce with AJAX), it does not!

I tried it in my project with codes and middle-ware and everything is right, but it's not working!

Any Help Would be Appreciated.

B.t.w.: The address I'm trying to scrape is: http://lastsecond.ir/tours/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be python, you can use pygi or pyqt with full on webkit browsers.  Then inject arbitrary JS on the page or parse the dom however you prefer.  It's a full on browser, so heavier than some frameworks - it does just work though, unless you're trying to parse DOM rewrites on something that uses a shadow DOM.